# Google maps API map centres on 0,0 and zooms fully in

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, kml

I'm trying to code a basic 'display a map from KML' website, and am getting an opaque failure. I was hoping someone could have a look at the code below, and tell me if there are any novice errors.

The malfunction is that when I run it, the map goes fully zoomed in on (0,0), rather than displaying all my pointers encoded in the KML. The KML it points to *ought* to be valid. It was working some time ago, and I'm not sure what I changed, if anything. It's based very strongly on a Google example.

Apologies for the generality of the question -- I really am just starting out. Many thanks in advance.

Mark

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=0.5, user-scalable=yes" />
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1800">
<style type="text/css">
html { height: 100% }
body { height: 100%; width: 500px; margin: 0px auto; text-align:center; padding: 0 }
map_canvas { height: 65% }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAQylgnaeGmmExmZio2e2zixSRHOaWUj2I&amp;sensor=false">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function initialize() {
var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(55, 2); 
var myOptions = {
zoom: 6,
center: latlng,
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
} 
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
var trip_layer = new google.maps.KmlLayer('http://mc711.user.srcf.net/vacation/trip.1339139845.kml');
trip_layer.setMap(map);
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="initialize()">
<div id="Notes" style="width: 75%; font-size:48; font-family:sans-serif;  text-align:center; margin:0px auto;">Mark's location</div>
<div id="map_canvas" style="width: 100%; height: 480px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I get a 404 error when trying to access http://mc711.user.srcf.net/vacation/trip.1339139845.kml

Comment: Ah, thanks for catching that. Seems to have been the problem -- changed enclosing directories recently.

Comment: yes, reference to your KML is not valid anymore - it works fine when I substitute the KML url with another existing one. If changing the URL solves your issue you should close this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your KML file is not there, so it returns a 404 - Not found:
http://mc711.user.srcf.net/vacation/trip.1339139845.kml